# Передать значения из js в базу

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap, smarty

имеется `Form`

**Код формы**

```
<form>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="postform"/>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body form-horizontal payment-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Имя<a style="color: red">*</a></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">   
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" value= "{if isset($usrData)}{$usrData.firstname}{/if}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Фамилия<a style="color: red">*</a></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" value= "{if isset($usrData)}{$usrData.lastname}{/if}">
                        </div>
                    </div> <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="middlename" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Отчество</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="middlename" value="{if isset($usrData)}{$usrData.middlename}{/if}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contacts" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Телефон<a style="color: red">*</a></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contacts" value="{if isset($usrData)}{$usrData.contacts}{/if}">
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Электроная почта<a style="color: red">*</a></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{if isset($usrData)}{$usrData.email}{/if}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="selecthotels" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Выберете место</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select class="form-control" id="selecthotels" name="selecthotels">
                             {foreach from=$hotels key=id item=val}
                                <option value="{$val.id}">{$val.hotelname}</option>
                             {/foreach}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="selectrooms" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Выберете комнату</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select class="form-control" id="selectrooms" name="selectrooms">
                             {foreach from=$booking key=id item=val}
                                <option value="{$val.id}">{$val.rooms}</option>
                             {/foreach}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="dateto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата заезда</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateto" name="dateto">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="datefrom" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата выезда</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefrom" name="datefrom">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default preview-add-button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Добавить
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div> <!-- / panel preview -->
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h4>Предпросмотр:</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table preview-table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Имя</th>
                                    <th>Фамилия</th>
                                    <th>Отчество</th>
                                    <th>Телефон</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Место</th>
                                    <th>Комната</th>
                                    <th>Заезд</th>
                                    <th>Выезд</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody> <!-- preview content goes here-->
                        </table>
                    </div>                            
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-right">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h4>Итого: <strong><span class="preview-total"></span></strong></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <hr style="border:1px dashed #dddddd;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block add_button_to_base">Подтвердить ваш выбор и перейти к оплате!</button>
                </div>                
            </div>
            </form>
```

При нажатии на кнопку добавить передаётся в javascript и отображается в предпросмотре

**код js**

```
$(function(){
    $('.preview-add-button').click(function(){
        var form_data = {};
        form_data["firstname"] = $('.payment-form input[name="firstname"]').val();
        form_data["lastname"] = $('.payment-form input[name="lastname"]').val();
        form_data["middlename"] = $('.payment-form input[name="middlename"]').val();
        form_data["contacts"] = $('.payment-form input[name="contacts"]').val();
        form_data["email"] = $('.payment-form input[name="email"]').val();
        form_data["selecthotels"] = $('.payment-form #selecthotels option:selected').text();
        form_data["selectrooms"] = $('.payment-form #selectrooms option:selected').text();
        form_data["dateto"] = $('.payment-form input[name="dateto"]').val();
        form_data["datefrom"] = $('.payment-form input[name="datefrom"]').val();
        form_data["remove-row"] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');
        $.each(form_data, function( type, value ) {
            $('<td class="input-'+type+'"></td>').html(value).appendTo(row);
        });
        $('.preview-table > tbody:last').append(row); 
        calc_total();
    });

});
```

Но возникла необходимость передать значения из javascript в базу т.е если я добавлю 10 записей то все 10 записей нужно положить в базу, прошу оказать помощь добавления в базу.

Заранее благодарен.

Использую FrameWork Smarty и Bootstrap

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ||  http://webdevelopingcat.com/jquery-php-beginner-tutorial-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

нужно добавить ajax запрос, в качестве данных передать form_data